# Converting Ibatis to Mybatis

Tags: spring, mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

I am new to this frameworks I have a project which uses spring-ibatis .my job is to convert that to spring-mybatis.Can anyone suggest me what would be the starting point to accomplish this Job.
import org.springframework.orm.ibatis.support.SqlMapClientDaoSupport;

```
import java.util.*;

public class PortTrackerDataDAOImpl extends SqlMapClientDaoSupport implements PortTrackerDataDAO {

    public List<?> getTypeLookup()
    {
        return this.getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryForList("getTypeLookup", null);
    }

    public List<?> getNavLookup()
    {
        return this.getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryForList("getNavLookup", null);
    }

    public List<?> getMarketDays(Date extractDate)
    {
        return this.getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryForList("getMarketDays", extractDate);
    }

    public List<?> getAccountDetail(Integer webUserId)
    {
        return this.getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryForList("getAccountDetail", webUserId);
    }

    public List<?> getFalPositions(String acctNo)
    {
        return this.getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryForList("getFalPositions", acctNo);
    }

    public Double getFalBalance(String acctNo)
    {
        return (Double) this.getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryForObject("getFalBalance", acctNo);
    }

    public Double getDSTShares(String fundNo, String region, String acctNo)
    {
        Map<String, String> parm = createParameterMap( fundNo,  region,  acctNo);
        return (Double) this.getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryForObject("getDSTShares", parm);
    }

    public List<?> getFlaggedUsers(Date updatedDt)
    {
        return this.getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryForList("getFlaggedUsers", updatedDt);
    }

    public List<?> getFlaggedUsersOnly()
    {
        return this.getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryForList("getFlaggedUsersOnly", null);
    }

    public void resetFlaggedUsers(Integer webUserId)
    {
        this.getSqlMapClientTemplate().update("resetFlaggedUsers", webUserId);
    }

    private Map<String, String> createParameterMap(String fundNo, String region, String acctNo)
    {

        Map<String, String> paramMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        paramMap.put("region", region);
        paramMap.put("fundNo", fundNo);
        paramMap.put("acctNo", acctNo);

        return paramMap;
    }

}
```

Comment: One obvious thing would be to update version number and fix whatever errors pop up (using documentation and migration guide if needed), but you must've tried that before posting your question, right? In that case include the details of bits that don't work and you can't figure out.

Comment: I have added spring-mybatis in pom and removed ibatis. in the above class I am getting error at import org.springframework.orm.ibatis.support.SqlMapClientDaoSupport .

Comment: This is the part when you start searching for possible solutions; [the first Google result](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/ibatis/support/SqlMapClientDaoSupport.html) for "sqlmapclientdaosupport mybatis" says "Deprecated. as of Spring 3.2, in favor of the native Spring support in the Mybatis follow-up project". Let's search... oh, https://mybatis.github.io/spring/ - this looks promising! And so on, and so on - another day in the life of a software engineer.

Comment: Thanks Kryger your comment motivates me.